# Best way to load content into application

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, database

I have a project where I need to write text from a database into an HTML5 canvas / Javascript application.

To select this content, I've specified an attribute "reference" where I can ask the database with the content id, for example: index.php?reference=exercise1.

I have used AJAX because I need to get the text content into a Javascript variable in order to write data on canvas.
My solution is working but I need to get the reference attribute value from Javascript document.URL and not PHP $_GET.

Here is the code:

```
var url = decodeURIComponent(document.URL);
var attr = "reference";
var attrPos = url.lastIndexOf(attr);
var referencePos = attrPos + attr.length + 1;
var reference = url.substr(referencePos,url.length);
```

What I'm doing seems not to be the clean way to me.

First, ?reference= should be used with PHP $_GET and not be hacked through Javascript.

Then, I have to use lastIndexOf() instead of the search() method in order to get the good value if my application is located in a folder named "reference".

Still, if I have my project in a folder named "reference" with a URI like localhost/reference/projectfolder/index.php and a reference named "projectfolder" in the database, it will load the content even if I have not asked for index.php?reference=projectfolder

From your experience, what is the best solution in my case: be able to get PHP/MySQL data to use with Javascript. Ajax seems to be the best way but as you can see it's not clean, at least my solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to use the URI? Why wouldnt you just set the reference as a js variable when the page first loads like `<?php echo "var currentReference = ". json_encode(($reference ? $reference : null)) . ";" ?>`

Comment: @prodigitalson I have a Javascript class, external js file as my main program where I access and write into canvas so I think it isn't a good solution to print variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Still, if I have my project in a folder named "reference" with a URI
>   like localhost/reference/projectfolder/index.php and a reference named
>   "projectfolder" in the database, it will load the content even if I
>   have not asked for index.php?reference=projectfolder

if you want the document to be empty when you are requesting just index.php, check if $_GET["reference"] is set and then return an empty body.

> From your experience, what is the best solution in my case: be able to
>   get PHP/MySQL data to use with Javascript. Ajax seems to be the best
>   way but as you can see it's not clean, at least my solution.

Check this gist on how to return JSON in your body https://gist.github.com/2627924

Comment: what I need is to return JSON in my Javascript external file so I can load content in canvas

Comment: you get the JSON with an get request using javascript. Is there any specific reason why you need to generate this in the file first? Then you would have to do that in PHP, and then call some PHP script that updates your eternal javascript file before retrieving it

Comment: I'm actually doing what you describe, getting JSON data with Javascript request (Ajax) but creating a new file to write content has non sense for me since I already have a Javascript class with every functions to read/write on canvas :/

Comment: Getting data in the body makes public variables and mess my Javascript classes but this solution is ok for the moment. It's better and cleaner compared to what I have before, thanks.